# How to resize the usercontrol in wpf resizing

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

In my wpf project I have one main window(Mainwindow.xaml) file and remaining all windows are user controls. If I click any menu of the mainwindow.xaml then the corresponding usercontrols will appear in the mainwindow.xaml form.

My requirement is, when the usercontrol window is resized, I need to resize all controls width (i.e textboxes,comoboxes,..etc). How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the components you need to resize dynamically should not have fixed sizes. You should put everithing into Grid and set width/height to "Auto"/"x*"/ Alignment to stretch...

    `<UserControl ...>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/><!--2/5 of total height-->
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">Text </TextBlock>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2" >Enter</TextBox>
            <TextBox  Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Button 5 Button 5 Button 5 Button 5</TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>`

Main

    `<Grid Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ContentControl ..." />
    </Grid>`

Comment: I am new to WPF and I don't know why and I don't know how but by copy / pasting this it solved my problem. Now I need to tweak with the x* values. Thanks. And the ColumnSpan is a nice one. Especially when using DataGrid as I do.